# value returned from ajax call not getting set to variable in controller in angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, angularjs

**HTML**

```
<div id="SalaryDiv">
    <div ng-controller="SalaryController as sal">
       <div ng-repeat="salaryDetail in sal.data">
           <p>{{salaryDetail.Name}}</p>
           <p>{{salaryDetail.Salary}}</p>    
       </div>    
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
(function () {

    var salary = angular.module("SalaryDetails", []);

    salary.controller("SalaryController", function () {
        var newData = getAssociateData();
        alert(newData);  //here it is alerting as undefined
        this.data = salaryDetails;
    });

    function getAssociateData() {
        var returnData;
        $.ajax({
            url: "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/vigneshvdm/862ec5a97bbbe2021b79/raw/d7155b9c7fd533597c912fc386682e5baee1487a/associate.json",
            type: "GET",
            success: getDetails
        });

        function getDetails(data) {
            salaryDetails = data;
            return data;
        };
    };

}());
```

Here the success function is getting called,
but value is not getting set

Comment: try making `factory` for your ajax calls to set values in your module variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) The return value from `getAssociateData` is whatever the return value is of `$.ajax` - which is NOT the `data` that you return. `$.ajax` is an **async** call.

2) You should use Angular's `$http` rather than jQuery's `$.ajax` - this would apply the changes to the View automatically (i.e. it will call `$scope.$apply()` on your behalf).

You also seem to be expecting `this.data` to be an array (I gather from the use of `ng-repeat="salaryDetail in sal.data"`, so `push` instead of assigning.

```
salary.controller("SalaryController", function ($http) {
  var url = "https://gist.gith....json";
  var vm = this; // your "Controller As" ViewModel
  vm.data = [];
  $http.get(url).then(function(salaryDetail){
     vm.data.push(salaryDetail);
  }
}
```

This is by way of illustration. I agree with other suggestions here that HTTP calls should be abstracted away in a Service, rather than keeping them in the controller. But, one step at a time...

Comment: Thanks ! it says .push is not defined

Comment: You should create a factory to have your $http calls over their instead of having it directly in controller, i doubt this will work as $http does not invoke $digest calls automatically

Comment: @vignesh, yes, you're right - `this` doesn't refer to your controller - fixed

Comment: @V31, `$http` and other Angular services (e.g. `$timeout`) "automagically" deal with `$scope`

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) service.

```
salary.controller("SalaryController", function ($scope, $http) {

    $scope.salaryDetails = null;

    var url = 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/vigneshvdm/862ec5a97bbbe2021b79/raw/d7155b9c7fd533597c912fc386682e5baee1487a/associate.json';
    $http.get(url).
        success(function (data) {
            $scope.salaryDetails = data;
        });
});
```

Note: I put it in the controller here, but as a best practice, you should only inject an `$http` dependency into your custom service.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you trying to call an ajax call inside the controller, it will not fire the angular digest and hence the controller variables wont get updated.

The ideal way to go about it to have this in a factory and then call the factory method from the controller.

Code example:

```
appModule.factory('Search', function($rootScope, $http, $q) {
  return {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http.get('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/vigneshvdm/862ec5a97bbbe2021b79/raw/d7155b9c7fd533597c912fc386682e5baee1487a/associate.json').success(function(response) {
      deferred.resolve({
         data: response)};
    });
  return deferred.promise;
 }
});
```

This code is using $q service inorder to make it more cleaner.Now just inject this factory (Search) into your controller and use it as is.

Comment: You don't need all this hassle with `$q` - `$http` already returns a promise. Your factory is also not really returning a service object, so it shouldn't even work as written.